# Unable to create layer for WebView, size 640x7040 max size 8192 color type 4 has context 1

Tags: java, android, webview, samsung-mobile

I am using `WebView` inside ScrollView, and it is giving `IllegalStateException` on Samsung SM-J610F. It is working fine on the rest of the devices that I have tested this code on.

When I take out `WebView` out of `ScrollView` it works fine. But the problem is that I have other views below WebView and if I don't use `ScrollView`, the user will not be able to see those view.

```
Font Cache (CPU):
      Size: 103.02 kB 
      Glyph Count: 37 
    CPU Caches:
      Shadows: 4.22 KB (2 entries)
    GPU Caches:
      Other:
        Buffer Object: 63.00 KB (2 entries)
      Image:
        Texture: 1.81 MB (28 entries)
             Texture( 1):      168840 Byte (count:8)
             Texture( 2):       54288 Byte (count:1)
             Texture( 3):       44100 Byte (count:1)
             Texture( 4):       31684 Byte (count:6)
             Texture( 5):       29580 Byte (count:1)
             Texture( 6):       29568 Byte (count:1)
             Texture( 7):       29232 Byte (count:3)
             Texture( 8):       28896 Byte (count:1)
             Texture( 9):       28560 Byte (count:1)
             Texture(10):       11024 Byte (count:1)
             .......   
      Scratch:
        Texture: 512.00 KB (1 entry)
        RenderTarget: 1.46 MB (14 entries)
        Buffer Object: 96.03 KB (4 entries)
    Other Caches:
                             Current / Maximum
      VectorDrawableAtlas    0.00 kB /   0.00 KB (entries = 0)
      Layers Total           0.00 KB (numLayers = 0)
    Total GPU memory usage

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView, size 640x7040 max size 8192 color type 4 has context 1
......
```

Comment: We see this error on a very large app on Samsung Galaxy J6+, Samsung Galaxy J4+, Nokia 2.1. OS of all affected devices is Android 9.

Comment: @TimoBähr So you have no solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: can you provide more details about your view structure?

Comment: I started a thread in SAMSUNG's community, maybe they can help out: https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=372855&startId=zzzzz~

Answer (score 1):

Remove the webview out of the scroll view and place it individually. Also all the other views present add them inside of the Scrollview. This way your webview will be stable also, the users will be able to scroll and refer the other views.
Also, the webview should be declared and implemented properly:

```
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);      //webview page matches the screen size.
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);    //loads online website when no internet connection.
        wv.loadUrl("https://prajwalwaingankar.wixsite.com/nivala");
```

As per the above code, all the views are above of the webview and the webview covers up the rest of the remaining screen size using method
      **.setInitialScale(1);**

Comment: Removing the webview out of the scroll view is not possible in our setup as we show oEmbed/iFrames and native text parts together inside a scroll view. I'm talking about a news app and the article page.

Comment: @mughi198 Have you checked these settings on your J610F device. I could only test the suggested solution with the affected users doing a full release of the app.

Comment: yes, i have already tested above mentioned settings and this solution doesnt work for me. I had to change my application's design just to solve this issue

Comment: @mughi198 That was something I said to change your views and design

Comment: As written before, changing the design is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: @TimoBähr i have not found any other solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was `Unable to create layer for RNCWebViewManager$f, size 1080x9661 exceeds max size 8192` and triggered a crash on Android 8 Samsung and Huawei devices.

Removing the parent ScrollView was not an option in my case because that was really needed.

**Limiting the webview height to 2720 (DeviceSupported(8192)/3) fixed the issue.**

This was the only workaround I found to keep the `hardwareAccelerated` `true`

I had also to pass `overScrollMode={'never'}` as webview prop.